# Azure SQLite Insert

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure

I have an Azure cloud app and I'm trying to store user uploaded data in a SQLite database located in ~/AppData/mydb.db.  Due to numerous problems I was having deploying System.Data.SQLite, I modified my code to use this [sharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite) library.  Everything works fine when inserting data in debug mode.

When deployed on Azure, the user supplied data is inserted into the SQLite database.  No errors are thrown during this process.  However, when try to view the data (which should now exist in the database) nothing is there.  I also added a link on my web app so that I could download the database.  Downloading it verified that the data is not being saved.

It seems like Azure is preventing the database from being updated.  Has anyone experienced a similar problem.

Here is a sample of the code that I'm using:

```
Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteConnection cnn = new SqliteConnection("data source=file:" + Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\mydb.db"));
cnn.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data(x,y,z) VALUES(?,?,?)";

System.Data.Common.DbParameter X = cmd.CreateParameter();
System.Data.Common.DbParameter Y = cmd.CreateParameter();
System.Data.Common.DbParameter Z = cmd.CreateParameter();

cmd.Parameters.Add(X);
cmd.Parameters.Add(Y);
cmd.Parameters.Add(Z);

X.Value = "some"
Y.Value = "sample"
Z.Value = "data"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbTrans.Commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you experience might be with your approach.

When you say "*Azure cloud*" I assume you refer to [Azure Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/what-is-a-cloud-service/) (not Azure Website).

As far as the Azure Cloud services are concerned, your deployment *service package* (the service package contains the application code and the service definition file) should be considered as a *sealed package* which cannot be modified by your code. However, what your are trying to perform is updated of your internal package resource `mydb.db` file (by performing some SQL insert which would result in `mydb.db` file update).

The approach of having *service package* *immutable* is by design. There are some points supporting that decision:

- Many roles (of the same type) can handle the request (assuming you have more than one instance of the specific web role); that's why your *service package* needs to be identical across all the instances.
- Azure performed routine maintenance or patching of the operating systems and recreated your instance from the *service package*
- Azure attempted to recover from service or hardware failure – again, your instance has been rebuilt from *service package*

I think the best solution with Azure Cloud services is to use cloud-optimized solution such as Azure SQL database.

If you really need to use SQLite, I would recommend using [Azure Website](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/) instead of [Azure Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/what-is-a-cloud-service/). With Azure Website, changes to your resource will be updated and visible by other website instances.

Comment: I am doing something similar and using azure websites and I can read and write to a SQLite Db without issue.  Tom is spot on.

Comment: @Tom, With an Azure Website, I thought the same "sealed deployment package" concept was applicable? Azure websites can be scaled to multiple instances, and in such a case, isn't a write only going to be saved onto a single instance? Also, I do realize that this answer is over a year old, perhaps the way Azzure websites work has changed?

Comment: @Josh, Azure Websites share file system based on Azure Blob, using the standard SMB 2.1 protocol. Although Azure Website instances are independent (e.g. crash of one instance will not affect the other instances), they share the same file system and therefore changes written by one instance can be seen by all the others.

Comment: Very good to know! Do you have a reference that describes this behavior?

Comment: Found it: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-available-operating-system-functionality/#multipleinstances

Comment: That's a good page. You can also read about technical details over here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx

Comment: @ElvisLives I am really curious how you made it work. I still have issues trying to make it work. This is my problem described: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016128/sqlite-database-file-can-not-be-accessed-on-azure-hosted-asp-net-web-api-project